# Storing variables in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that returns dates greater than 16/02/2022 and the number of this dates (count) where a column is more than 1(CALCULUS).

I want the dates that returns me this query in a VARIABLE.
**¿Can I save the exact dates and the count in a VARIABLE?**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) N, DATE
FROM  Table1
WHERE DATE >='16/02/2022'
AND CALCULUS > 1
GROUP BY DATE
```

Comment: you mean like collecting the query result in a variable?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Collect the result of the query in a variable.

Comment: What do you want to do with the dates and counts? Are you using them in a PL/SQL function/procedure? Do you want to use them in second SQL statement? If it is the latter then do not try to save the results and just include the first query in the second query as an inline view. Do you want to use the results in multiple SQL statements? In which case, you probably want PL/SQL for that. However, you should [edit] your question to provide a [MRE] with an example of how you are going to use the results.

Comment: `DATE` is a reserved word and you cannot use it as an unquoted identifier. Also, `'16/02/2022'` is not a date, it is a string literal (that may look like a date); you should use a date literal or use `TO_DATE` to convert the string to a date (with an explicit format model).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option; you'll need PL/SQL for that.

- `select` (line #8) stores the result into a locally declared collection
- the result is then displayed in the `for` loop (line #15)

---

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    type    t_rec is record (cnt number,
  3                             datum date
  4                            );
  5    type    t_tab is table of t_rec index by binary_integer;
  6    l_tab   t_tab;
  7  begin
  8    select count(*), hiredate
  9      bulk collect into l_tab
 10      from emp
 11      where hiredate > date '1980-01-01'
 12        and empno >= 7900
 13      group by hiredate;
 14
 15    for i in l_tab.first .. l_tab.last loop
 16      dbms_output.put_line(l_tab(i).datum ||': '|| l_tab(i).cnt);
 17    end loop;
 18  end;
 19  /
03.12.1981: 2
23.01.1982: 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

and here is another way to work with the query result:

```sql
declare
    cursor cur_dates is
    select count(*) n, datum
    from table1
    where datum >= '16/02/2022'
    and calculus > 1
    group by date;
    
begin 
    for r in cur_dates loop
        /*do your stuff here*/ 
        end loop ;
end;
```